# Cannot get value from an object within a list in GSP

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I am a newbie in Groovy and grails. I want to display the current project of an employee in employee List. I can only get the current project of an employee by going to `ProjectMember` class. My idea is that I get the current project of every employee and then put it in a list which I then iterate over in the `.gsp`.

```
class EmployeeController {

    def list = {
        params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10, 100)

        def currentProject = [ProjectMember];
        List<Employee> employeeList = Employee.list(params)
        System.out.print("PREV SIZE" + currentProject.size())
        for(Employee emp: employeeList) {
            def current = ProjectMember.findAllByEmployeeAndEndDateIsNull(emp, [sort: "project.name", order: "asc"])
            System.out.print(current.project.name);
            // This is working, I can get the current projects of the employee
            if(!current.empty) {                     
                currentProject.add(current);
                // Here is the code I didn't understand I really don't know 
                // if the project is added in the list.
                // Everytime I try to display the contents of the list using foreach, 
                // I always get an error. MissingProperty
            }
        }

        [currentProject: currentProject,
         employeeInstanceList: Employee.list(params),
         employeeInstanceTotal: Employee.count()]
    }
}
```

---

```
class ProjectMember {
    Employee employee
    EmployeeRole role
    Date startDate
    Date endDate
    String notes

    static belongsTo = [project: Project]
}
```

---

```
class Project {
    String name
    String alternateName
    boolean useAlternateNameInResume = false

    String summary
    String duration
    String skills
    String technologies

    Date startDate
    Date endDate

    static hasMany = [members: ProjectMember]
}
```

---

And lastly the view, `list.gsp`:

```
<g:each in="${employeeInstanceList}" status="i" var="employeeInstance">
    <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'} clickable" onclick="window.location='<g:createLink action='show' id='${employeeInstance.id}' />'">
        <td>${employeeInstance.idNo?.encodeAsHTML()}</td>
        <td>${fieldValue(bean: employeeInstance, field: "fullNameWithMiddleName")}</td>
        <td>${employeeInstance.position}</td>
        <td>
            <g:each in="${currentProject}" var="currentProject" status ="j">                                            
                ${fieldValue(bean: currentProject, field: "project.name")}
            </g:each>
            <g:if test="${currentProject.empty}">
                No projects yet
            </g:if> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</g:each>
```

Everything works fine except for the current project which doesn't display anything.

Comment: yes,. nothing displays. Is there anything wrong in my code?

Comment: currentProject is initialized to a list with ProjectMember.class as its single member. This looks strange and might lead to an unexpected behaviour of the gsp when it tries to get the class' project.name property. Maybe "def currentProject = []" would be the correct initialization?

Comment: BTW, overloading names in gsp is bad practice. The scopes of those vars is not as obvious as you might think.

Comment: I see, the currentProject list is not readable in gsp? I've changed the def currentProject = [ProjectMember] into def currentProject = []. nothing displayed again. How can I initialized the currentProject from the controller be readable in the gsp?

Comment: Use a debugger :). Put a breakpoint in that `if(!current.empty)` and see what happens when the program runs, what are the values of the variables, etc.

Comment: Also, try both the advices johanneslink mentions. The initialization of the `currentProject` list seems wrong, as it is a list of Class objects and then ProjectMembers are added to it. Also change the name of `currentProject` to `currentProjects`, as it is a list of things (thus should be plural) and then change `<g:each in="${currentProject}" var="currentProject" ...` to `<g:each in="${currentProjects}" var="currentProject" ...`. And finally, you can use `println` directly instead of `System.out.print`, or better, use the logging functions like `log.info` or `log.debug` thar controllers have.

Comment: One more thing: With 'currentProject.add(current)' you add a collection to another collection which does not add all elements. Try 'currentProject.addAll(current)' instead.

That said: You should give your vars names which show that they are collections like currentProject_s_; this can prevent many of the trivial programming errors.

Comment: it works now! thanks to all! thanks @johanneslink, i followed your advice, I changed def currentProject[ProjectMember] to def currentProject = []. and it works now! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<g:each in="${currentProject}" var="project">                                            
     ${fieldValue(bean: project, field: "name")}
</g:each>
```

Comment: still. nothing happens. I think it doesn't go to the loop.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if this worked since the defined var (currentProject) is never referenced in the code.